# Convert Java.IO.File to Android.Net.Uri

Tags: android

In my Xamarin.Android application I have the following code:

```
private Android.Media.Image mImage;
private Java.IO.File mFile;

public void Run()
{
    ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
    buffer.Get(bytes);

    using (var output = new FileOutputStream(mFile))
    {
        try
        {
            output.Write(bytes);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            mImage.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am saving my image to a `Java.IO.File` but I would like to have reference to it as a `Android.Net.Uri` so I can use it to set my `ImageView` later. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Uri.fromFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#fromFile(java.io.File)) is what you'd use to create a `Uri` that points to a `File`.